# What might cause Office 2010 Excel to crash when pasting from Access

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I'm using Windows 7 and Office 2010 on a new machine so both are fairly new installations and have been fully updated.  For the most part things with office have been fine, but when trying to work on a fairly large and complicated Excel file I'm having trouble copying about 4000 rows (and 15 columns) of data from an Access query into an Excel table.  As soon as I paste the data I get a fairly useless error message saying "Excel as stopped working", Windows then takes a couple minutes to look for a solution, create a recovery file (which never works) and restart Excel. I've tried starting Excel in safe mode, but the same problem occurs.

The data itself is fairly simple, but the Excel sheet contains an table with several additional columns with formulas that are then pulled into a half-dozen pivot tables on 3 other sheets in the workbook.

The work around I found is to paste into an empty Excel sheet, then copy and paste from there into the complex workbook.

Are there known issues when moving data into Excel 2010 that I should be on the look out for or could address?

Comment: Do you use any kind of Clipboard manager software? Anti-virus?

Comment: No clipboard manager.  Symantec Endpoint Protection is running.

Comment: The data coming from Access may be simple, but what datatypes are used in the Access table. Are there any memo fields?

Comment: Mostly "Text", a couple "Number" nothing else.